# After Python steup.py build And Python setup.py install What to do next?

Tags: python, open-source, statsmodels

[enter link description here](http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/index.html)

I have successfully install the python setup.py build and  Python setup.py install and it takes about 5-10 minutes after that what is installed i am not knowing because i am only able to stats-models site-packages in python lib.
My question is that after compiling what is installed and what we can do with it is there any tutorials or book related to it i am new to this org probably 5-8 days but i know python .
So please tell me that after installing what is installed in my pc and where can i access that ????
And egg are made what is egg i don't know ???
Please tell me how to use it if any one can help by any tutorials or book 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ybn9h.png)

Answer (score 0):

WIth installation of python, idle is also be there in your pc, just search in search bar.
also set the path for pip for installing multiple packages.
in idle, you simply can run multiple programms.